# C Program slowing down after a couple read-ins

Tags: c

So i have to write a C program for class, that solves a connect four like game, that roughly said resolves matches of same colored pieces, lets pieces above fall down, then checks again for matches, if no matches were found it drops the next piece and so on.

My given input is a text file, where each line holds information about the color and the x-position, where the piece is supposed to fall down.
My implementation is based on AVL-trees and my program works fine for inputs roughly up to 2.000.000 lines and solves it in about 3 seconds.
One bigger example file i have to solve is roughtly 2.600.000 lines long but doesnt terminate.
The program reads in about 1.000.000 lines per second but right after about the 2.000.000 mark its slows down tremendously and only reads in a couple 100 lines per second.

Its one of my first "bigger" projects and has about 900 lines of code, so i dont see the point in posting it here (unless someone really wants to see it)

I am really clueless what the cause could be, so maybe someone of you has an idea or can point me in a direction for things i have to look out for.

Comment: We would have to see the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Break it down into a short example that produces the result and post the short example. (memory exhaustion is a possibility)

Comment: Did you try profiling it to see what takes up all that time? You didn't specify your platform - [here is a guide for Linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/profile-c-program-linux-using-gprof/). You can also google `profile c program <your platform>` to find something relevant. There are tools like [Google's Orbit](https://github.com/google/orbit) as well.

Comment: Just a blind guess.... Do you remove data from memory from time to time or do you just pile up everything? If you fill up your memory you might run into out of memory situation where the OS starts swapping RAM to disk and back which will make your performance drop like a stone

Comment: my platform is linux, the problem i am facing with profiling is that my program doesnt really terminate unless i let it run for hours. so it is not generating a gmon.out file

Comment: What about trying some other files sizes in between? There should be some line count that is somewhere between "3 seconds" and "does not terminate after hours". Maybe 2,100,000 line or 2,200,000 lines...

Comment: Does your algorithm limit the lines that are checked for connected tiles to those lines affected by previous falling tile or do you search all lines that you have piled up every time? Did you check how many lines of blocks you have to search after a certain line numer in the file?

Comment: yes my algorithm is limiting the area i have to search. its smallest resolved x - 3, largest resolved x +3 and smallest resolved y -3

Comment: There have been a few more suggestions you might want to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

Add logging with timestamps to spot where the slowdown occurs.  You need to isolate the code that has the performance issue.

The first step to getting better is to measure where you currently are.  Once you know how long the current process takes, you can decide if a change you make helps, hurts or makes no change.

There's a vast world of software optimization, look around for expensive loops.  Read up on big oh notation.  If you have a loop that processes a loop that processes a loop O(n^3), what seems fast with 100 iterations each can slow down dramatically when each loop is a million.

If you have a performance profiler it can help organize the timestamps from the logs it creates so that the code that's taking the most time is highlighted.  Many times what happens in cases like this is that something that seems good enough when you start out isn't good enough once you start to scale.

Nobody says you have to add log to every single line of your source code.  That can be overwhelming.  Figuring out what you don't have to focus on can be very helpful.

Comment: Ehm, I anticipate about two million, six hundred thousand lines of logging before you see anything substantial.  It might not even show up in the log.